# How to get different values ​when generating an element through Object.keys?

Tags: reactjs

I create a sidebar through the **object.keys(sidebars)**, and in each of them there are various menu items that I get from the database, how to change these elements in state.items? To access the item field during generation and display these menu items?

Now I do like this, but nothing comes of it ...

```
const [sidebarItemsLeagues, setSidebarItemsLeagues] = useState(null); // SIDEBAR 1 ITEMS
const [sidebarItemsCountries, setSidebarItemsCountries] = useState(null); // SIDEBAR 2 ITEMS

const [sidebars] = useState({
    leagues: {
        title: "SIDEBAR 1", 
        items: sidebarItemsLeagues // null...
    },
    countries: {
        title: "SIDEBAR 2",
        items: sidebarItemsCountries // null...
    }
});

useEffect(() => {
    api.getTestLeagues() // get sidebar 1 items
    .then(data => setSidebarItemsLeagues(data)); 
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    api.getTestCountries() // get sidebar 2 items
    .then(data => setSidebarItemsCountries(data));
}, [])

const onHandleSidebarView = () => { // generate sidebars
    return (
        Object.keys(sidebars).map((sidebar, idx) => {
            const sidebarControl = sidebars[sidebar];
            return (
                <div className="sidebar" key={idx}>
                    <div className="sidebar__header">
                    <p>{sidebarControl.title}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="sidebar__items">
                    // SIDEBAR 1 && SIDEBAR 2 ITEMS
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` notation back onto your object to access its corresponding property dynamically. I changed the map to use `key` for more clarity

```
    Object.keys(sidebars).map((key, idx) => {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar" key={idx}>
                <div className="sidebar__header">
                <p>{sidebars[key].title}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="sidebar__items">
                {
                    // SIDEBAR ITEMS (assuming it contains an array)
                    sidebars[key].items.map(itemElement => {
                        // return some elements
                    }
                }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    })
```

Comment: How to get items?

Comment: @reacter I added an example in my answer assuming it contains an array